# Prove that $\operatorname{SL}(n,\Bbb R)$ is connected.

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, topological-groups

Prove that $\operatorname{SL}(n, \Bbb R)$ is connected.

The problem is I know only topological groups from Munkres only. Again Just started fundamental groups. So if anyone can explain to me how it is true in a lucid language and in an easy way such that it remains in my boundary of knowledge then it would be a great help. I have mentioned what I know.
Again if tag this in the wrong field. Please forgive me.

Comment: Since you asked, my opinion is that you don't need the algebraic topology tag.

Comment: On the other hand a linear-algebra tag would be very appropriate since, as the answer of @mookid shows, this is a consequence of basic facts in basic linear algebra.

Comment: Could one show a stronger statement, that $SL_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is path connected?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint:** prove that if two matrices can be transformed one into another using row-echelon transformation, then they are connected.

---

as we focus on elements of $SL_n$, we only need to prove that transvections $L_i \to l_i + aL_j$ connect elements.

let $A\in SL_n$, $B$ is the image of $A$ under the transvection $L_i \to L_i + aL_j$.

Then
$$
\gamma: [0,1]\to SL_n
$$defined by
"$\gamma(t)$ is the image of $A$ under the transvection  $L_i \to L_i + taL_j$
" is continuous, and such as $\gamma(0) = A$, $\gamma(1) = B$ (also, check that for every $t$, $\gamma (t)\in SL_n$). Hence $A,B$ are path connected.

Comment: How do I do that? Using topological group definition?

Comment: the transformations have explicit forms. Use the 'path-connected implies connected' implication.

Comment: can you please write this answer ilaborately then atleast I get an idea for this kind of questions.

Comment: Because I am new to deal with these questions. Thats why I am requesting you. Please it will be a great help.

Comment: @user152715 I wrote the hint part. Now it is your turn to finish the proof. Tell me if you have other issues.

Comment: No actually What is $L_i,L_j,a,l_i$ ? and does transvection mean translation?

Comment: $L_i$ is the $i$th line. $L_i→L_i+aL_j$ is the transformation which changes the $i$th line to itself $+ a\times $ the $j$th line. This is called a transvection.

Comment: Means $i$-th row if $A$?

Comment: yes, sorry. ${{{{}}}}$

Answer (score 16):

> **Exercise 2.M.8(a) (Artin's *Algebra*, 2nd edition).** The group $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is generated by elementary matrices of the first type (see Exercise 2.4.8). Use this fact to prove that $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is path-connected.

Let $\sim$ be the binary operation corresponding to path-connectivity in $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$; by my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820941/about-path-connected/1449691#1449691), $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

In order to show $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ is path-connected, it suffices to show $A\sim I_n$ for all $A\in SL_n(\mathbb{R})$. But by my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654206/why-is-the-special-linear-group-generated-by-elementary-matrices-that-add-a-mult/1449725#1449725), $A$ can be written as a (possibly empty) product of elementary matrices of the first type, so it in fact suffices to prove that$$E_{uv}(a)M\sim M$$for all $M\in SL_n(\mathbb{R})$ and Type 1 elementary matrices $E_{uv}(a)$ ($1\le u,\,v\le n$) of the form$$I_n + [a[(i,\,j) = (u,\,v)]]_{i,\,j\,=\,1}^n.$$Yet$$M\to E_{uv}(b)M$$simply adds $b$ times row $j$ to row $i$, i.e. takes $r_i$ to $r_i+br_j$. For fixed $u$, $v$, $M$, this map is continuous in $b$ (and preserves the determinant), so the continuous function$$X(t) = E_{uv}(ta)M$$over $[0,1]$ takes$$X(0) = M \to X(1) = E_{uv}(a)M$$while remaining inside $SL_n(\mathbb{R})$, as desired.

Answer (score 11):

$\textbf{Lemma: }$Let $Y$ be connected and $f\colon X\to Y$ be surjective continuous map having connected fibers. If $f$ is open, then $X$ is also connected.

*Proof.* We can prove this by contradiction. If possible, write $X=U\bigsqcup V$ where $U, V$ are non-empty open subsets of $X$. Then, $f(U),f(V)$ are open subsets of $Y$ such that $f(U)\cup f(V)=Y$. Now, $Y$ is connected implies $f(U)\cap f(V)\not=\varnothing.$ Take $y\in f(U)\cap f(V)$, then $f^{-1}(y)\cap U\not =\varnothing$ and $f^{-1}(y)\cap V\not=\varnothing$, contradicts to the fact that fibers are connected sets. $\square$

$\textbf{Theorem.}$ $\text{GL}^+(n,\Bbb R):=\big\{A\in \text{M}(n,\Bbb R): \det(A)>0\big\}$ is connected.

*Proof.* We will prove $\text{GL}^+(n,\Bbb R)$ is connected by induction on $n$.

Consider the map $p\colon \text{M}(n,\Bbb R)=\Bbb R^n\times \text{M}\big(n\times (n-1),\Bbb R\big)\longrightarrow \Bbb R^n$ given by $p(A)=Ae_1$. That is $p$ sends $A\in \text{M}(n,\Bbb R)$ to its first column. Note that $p$ is a projection map, hence open and continuous.

Note that, $\text{GL}^+(1,\Bbb R)=(0,\infty)$. Now, let $f\colon \text{GL}^+(n,\Bbb R)\longrightarrow \Bbb R^n\setminus\{0\}$ be the restriction of $p$ to the $\text{GL}^+(n,\Bbb R)\subseteq_{\text{open}}\text{M}(n,\Bbb R)$. So, $f$ is also open continuous.

Next, $f^{-1}(e_1)=\Bbb R^{n-1}\times \text{GL}^+(n-1,\Bbb R)$, which is a connected set by induction. For $y\in \Bbb R^n-\{0\}$ choose $B\in \text{GL}^+(n,\Bbb R)$ with $f(B)=y$. Then, $f^{-1}(y)=\big\{B\cdot C:C\in f^{-1}(e_1)\big\}$. Hence each fiber of $f$ is connected. So, $\text{GL}^+(n,\Bbb R)$ is connected by the above Lemma. $\square$

$\textbf{Theorem.}$ $\text{SL}(n,\Bbb R)$ is connected.

*Proof.* To prove $\text{SL}(n,\Bbb R)$ is connected, consider the continuous surjective map $$\Psi\colon \text{GL}^+(n,\Bbb R)\ni A\longmapsto \frac{A}{\det A}\in \text{SL}(n,\Bbb R).$$ Recall that continuous image of a connected set is connected, so we are done by the previous theorem. $\square$

Comment: $\mathrm{det}(A/\mathrm{det}(A))=1/\mathrm{det}(A)^{n-1}$.

Answer (score 3):

If you know the [connectedness of $SO(n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/711492/son-is-connected), there is an another approach.

Let $X \in SL(n) $ be given. By polar decomposition $X$ can be written as a product  $X=UP$, where $U$ is an orthogonal matrix and $P$ is a positive-definite symmetric matrix.
Here $\text{det}(U)=\text{det}(P)=1$ since $\text{det}(X)=1$. By the spectral theorem, $P=V^{-1}\mbox{diag}(\lambda_1, ... ,\lambda_n)V$ for some $V \in SO(n)$ and $\lambda_j \in (0, \infty)$.

This shows that the continuous map $$SO(n) \times SO(n) \times M \rightarrow SL(n)$$
given by $$\left( U, V, (x_1, ..., x_n) \right) \mapsto UV^{-1}\mbox{diag}(x_1, ..., x_n)V $$ is surjective, where $M$ denotes the embedded submanifold $\{(x_1, ..., x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n_{>0}  : x_1x_2...x_n=1\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^n_{>0}= \{(x_1, ..., x_n): x_1, ..., x_n >0 \}$.

To see M is (path) connected, let $(p_1, ..., p_n) \in M$ be given. Then $(p_1, ..., p_n)$ and $(1, p_1p_2, ...,p_n)$ is joined by the path

$$ t \mapsto (\frac{p_1}{\text{exp}(t \log p_1)}, \exp(t \log p_1)p_2, ... , p_n) $$

Inductively, we can construct a path from $(p_1, ..., p_n)$ to $(1, ..., 1)$.

As a product of connected spaces, $SO(n) \times SO(n) \times M$ is connected. Hence $SL(n)$ connected because it is a continuous image of a connected space.