# Unified theory of finitely generated groups and Lie groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, lie-groups, finitely-generated

I remember reading several times that Lie groups, and particularly compact Lie groups can be seen as analogous to finitely generated groups.

I can see the analogy between the generators, exponential map and so on but I don't know any formalization of those analogies.

Is there some theory unifying Lie groups and finitely generated groups ?

Comment: Can you link to a specific source that says this?

Comment: I can't find an "authoritative" source but the OP in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3368390/developing-intuition-for-lie-groups-and-lie-algebras is expressing the same idea regarding exponential, generators, etc.

Comment: There's one, which is "locally compact groups", and particularly compactly generated ones, which for discrete groups means finitely generated groups. If you're interested in harmonic analysis, this analogy is classical. In geometric group theory, it's a leitmotiv for the book [Metric geometry of locally compact groups](https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.3796) by myself and Pierre de la Harpe