# Prove that $\operatorname{SL}(n,\Bbb R)$ is connected using the decomposition $\exp(A)\exp(S)$

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Using this fact:

Every $X \in \operatorname{SL}(n,\Bbb R)$ can be decomposed as $X=\exp(A)\exp(S)$, with $A, B \in M_n(\Bbb R), \operatorname{tr}(A)=\operatorname{tr}(B)=0$ (i.e $A,B \in \mathfrak{sl}(n,\mathbb R)$) $A$ skew-symmetric, $S$ symmetric

**How can I prove that $\operatorname{SL}(n,\Bbb R)$ is connected?**

Comment: [Connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3241298/305862) (intended pun).

Comment: @Jean Marie. My question asks explicitly to use the described decomposition, which the answers in that link don't do

Comment: Don't you know in particular that "exponential of a skew symmetric matrix" is synonymous to "orthogonal matrix" ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I didn't. How can that be proven?

Comment: Show that the space $U$ of skew-symmetric matrices and the space $V$ of symmetric matrices are both connected, hence so is $U \times V$ which (you are told) is homeomorphic to $X$ via $(A, B) \mapsto \exp(A)\exp(B)$.

Comment: @RobArthan Could you elaborate on how to prove the connectedness of U and V? I don't know how to deal with spaces of matrices. This is to prove that exp of a skew symmetric matrix is the same as orthogonal, correct?

Comment: I've posted an answer. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: function $t \mapsto \exp((1-t)S)\exp((1-t)A)\quad\quad$ gives a path from $\exp(S)\exp(A)\quad$ to the identity matrix $I$. Use this to show that $\mathrm{SL}(n, \Bbb{R})$ is path-connected and hence connected.

Comment: for $  t=0$ I get $\exp S \exp A=X$. For t=1, the identity.

Comment: Don't I need two generic points to prove path-connectness? I mean $\alpha(0)=C, \alpha(1)=D$, matrices in $SL(n,\Bbb R)$ Instead of the particular X and I?

Comment: $S$ and $A$ are arbitrary and hence so is $X = \exp(S)\exp(A)$. So given arbitrary $X$ and $Y$, there is a path $\eta$ from $X$ to $I$ and a path $\zeta$ from $Y$ to $I$. If you compose $\eta$ with the reversal of $\zeta$ you get a path from  $X$ to $Y$.

Comment: Using this method, does itreally matter that A and S are skew-symmetric and symmetric? It doesn not seem to be used anywhere

Comment: The fact that $A$ and $S$ are skew-symmetric and symmetric is used to see that $(1-t)A$ and $(1-t)S$ are also skew-symmetric and symmetric so that the path stays inside $\mathrm{SL}()n, \Bbb{R})$. (This uses the (true) converse of the given fact.)